# ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows on Jupyter Notebook parsing a URL request

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am trying to parse my company Odata data to construct a proportion of late suppliers taking the CompanyName and LateDays fields.

I opened the file and converted it into a string since I found a really helpful post on how request urls with authentication, and I obtained my string text containing the whole report. The report is written in ?XML and I am using Python 3.7 in Jupyter Notebook to handle it.

I found another post that queries a XML file similar to mine using a class method, but my output is the error ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import base64
import urllib.request

request = urllib.request.Request('https://myUrl_OData')
base64string = base64.b64encode(bytes('%s:%s' % ('Myusername', 'Mypassword'),'ascii'))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string.decode('utf-8'))
result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
resulttext = result.read()

text = resulttext.decode(encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')

from xml.sax import parse
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class properties(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []          # stack of elements
        self.char_data = u''        # string buffer
        self.current_vendor = u'' 
        self.current_latedays = u''

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if companyname == u'CompanyName':
            self.elements.append(u'CompanyName')
        if latedays == u'LateDays':
            self.elements.append(u'LateDays')

    def characters(self, chars):
        if len(self.elements) > 0 and self.elements[-1] in [u'CompanyName', u'LateDays']:
            self.char_data += chars

    def endElement(self, name):
        self.elements.pop() if len(self.elements) > 0 else None

        if companyname == u'CompanyName':
            self.current_vendor = self.char_data
            self.char_data = ''
        if latedays == u'LateDays':
            self.current_latedays = self.char_data
            self.char_data = ''

        if companyname == 'CompanyName':
            if self.current_latedays == u'LateDays':
                print('Found:', self.current_customer)

            # clear the buffers now that is finished
            self.current_year = u''
            self.current_customer = u''
            self.char_data = u''


parse(r"\\\\?\\" + text, properties())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't seem to be related with XML parsing but with your OS limitations.
On a Windows-based OS, the path of a file cannot be longer than ~260 characters ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)).

Try to reduce the length of your filename, or reduce the number of nested folders leading to your data.